# Can I mask a Sprite in Haxe NME HTML5 target?

Tags: html, haxe

I have a really large PNG file that I would like to animate over time. Basically a "sprite sheet" using plain old HTML div `background-position-x` and `y` you can do this pretty easy. In Haxe NME I would like to so something like the following.

```
var sprite1 = new Sprite();
addChild(sprite1);

var spriteSheet = new Bitmap(Assets.getBitmapData("assets/someasset.png");
sprite1.addChild(spriteSheet);

var spriteMask = new Sprite();
spriteMask.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000, 1);
spriteMask.drawRect(0,0,400, 330);
spriteMask.endFill();
addChild(spriteMask);

sprite1.mask = spriteMask;
```

In Flash target this seems to work just fine but in HTML5 target all I get is a red square over the top of my sprite.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work. It would be really helpful to create animations using something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly neither mask nor scrollRect are implemented in Jeash (NME's HTML5).
https://bugs.launchpad.net/jeash/+bug/1001797

Comment: Philippe, I actually figured out that I could do bitmapdata swapping to solve my issue but it would be great if they would add masking to the html5 target so that I don't have to create 20-30 bitmaps and hold them in some sort of array just to do some sort of complex animation.

Comment: You could also "draw" in a bitmapData - it would be effectively like a square mask for the image you draw into.